# Grails - How to build a GUI with no DDL capabilites .I set the dbCreate="none"

Tags: grails

I am a ETL/BI/Stats resource stepping into  the areas of Grails(2.4.4) to build a simple UI:

> 

```
Column    Original Value            New Value 
> Fld 1   <display from schema.tbl>   <Overrides> 
> Fld 2   <display from schema.tbl>  <Overrides>
```

========================================================================

Here is how I am proceeding:

```
package poc_grails_ao

class FM8 {

    float   fld1 = 15
    String  fld2

    static mapping = {
        table Name  :FM8, schema:barsglobal
    }


}
```

The snippet of the dataSource.groovy on disabling  DDLs is:

```
dataSource {
            dbCreate = "none" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            //dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            //url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
            pooled = true
            driverClassName = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
            url = "jdbc:db2://hostname:port/DB Name"
            dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
            username = "id"
            password = "passwd"
```

On a non DB2 backend using H2, was able to build the screen. But on DB2 backend, after succesfull connections, run into the following error:

```
2016-02-11 14:59:15,144 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=THIS_.ID, DRIVER=3.61.65
Error |

ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - SqlSyntaxErrorException occurred when processing request: [GET] /POC_Grails_AO/FM8/index
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=THIS_.ID, DRIVER=3.61.65. Stacktrace follows:
Message: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=THIS_.ID, DRIVER=3.61.65
```

### **Crux of my question:**

```
a.Do  the "create-drop","create" etc options for dbCreate impact the live table objects on the DB2 backend or a "copy" of the schema being built within the Grails env?
b. Is it possible to allow only DMLs(updates to data only) and not allow any drop/updates to schemas.
c. How is the implementation( a syntax example for one col is awesome!)  to selectively choose few columns(Packed decimal, Strong, Date etc) from the DB2 table that would participate in the UI ?
```

Please do bear with me as I am making a quantum leap from a DWBI world to front-end GUI world and I am loving the potential of Grails for sure , thus far!

Thanks
Raghu

Answer (score 0):

First, welcome to SO and Grails!

Note that around here you only get one question per post. The first two are related so I'll cover those.

The answer is buried in the [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/conf.html#dataSource) so here's a copy of the **dbCreate** options:

- **create** - Drops the existing schema and creates the schema on startup, dropping existing tables, indexes, etc. first.
- **create-drop** - Same as create, but also drops the tables when the application shuts down cleanly.
- **update** - Creates missing tables and indexes, and updates the current schema without dropping any tables or data. Note that this can't properly handle many schema changes like column renames (you're left with the old column containing the existing data).
- **validate** - Makes no changes to your database. Compares the configuration with the existing database schema and reports warnings.
  any other value - does nothing

Based on this, `dbCreate = 'validate'` will do what you're looking for. However, this means you will need to create the tables yourself. You can get Grails to help you a bit by using the [schema-export](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/ref/Command%20Line/schema-export.html) command. For example, if you run: `grails prod schema-export` you'll get a file named ddl.sql containing the DB2 SQL DDL commands. *The schema-export* command also has the ability to run the SQL DDL. You can use this feature to create the initial database.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply!  Mad progress using validate. Before I post the error I ran into, wanted to clarify this point - since the tables(FM8 etc) all exist on the database(brdt004f) in their respective schema(BARSGLOBAL), I am not sure why I should create them locally in Grails env via the schema-export and then incur the effort to transfer/load the data from local tables to the target tables.Does Validate not allow a DML ? The data entry screen will have a subset of the fields from the tables involved.Your erudite thoughts please.Thanks again - RRK.

Comment: Correct, validate disallows ddl. It's useful in your case because you already have the tables. But let's say you want to create the same tables without the data to reproduce the database in another dbms instance; like a test system. schema-export is a way to do that. It only exports ddl.

Comment: Ok i messed up. Validate allows dml but not ddl.

Comment: oh no!, your inputs allowed me to make some progress! The char restriction to post forces very strong editing and the niceties suffer! Wanted to thank you for all your inputs and directions. In my next comment I will post an error I am running into.

Comment: ERRcontext.GrailsContextLoaderListener -Err initializing the application:Err creating bean with name transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed;nested exception is rg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Err creating bean with name 'transactionManager':Cant resolve ref to bean 'sessionFactory' while setng bean prpty 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory. BeanCreationException:Err creating bean with name sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: FM8

Comment: OK, that's a different question. So I recommend posting a new question for it, and make sure to place your `FM8` domain class source code in your question. It looks like either a problem with your domain class database mapping (the mapping closure) or the DB2 user account not having permission to read the table.

Comment: Can you recommend a good book to use as a user /reference manual that has step-by-step tutorial type exercises that would strenthen my learning curve? The goal is to essentially showcase the ease of building Applications using Grails to the larger Java community of developers in my organization.I purchase **Beginning Groovy & Grails - From Novice to Professional** by Chris,Joseph and James. Would have preferred a more hands on tutorial type book. Thanks in advance, Emmanuel Rosa!

Comment: The Grails book I have was (unknowingly) out-of-date when I bought it :( Besides, asking for recommendations around here is a good way to get your question closed, real quick. However, you are free to ask at the Grails mailing list and Slack communities. For what it's worth, I'm hosting a "Grails Hangout" tonight: http://emmanuelrosa.com/hangouts/grails/ Registration closed last Friday, but if you're interested I'll get you in. Just get with me on Google Hangouts: https://plus.google.com/109886199751744223967

Comment: I certainly will. Thanks for the accommodation! I read  comments on Amazon about **The Definitive Guide to Grails 2** authored by E.Rosa. Not sure if they are yours. But what I took away is that a) 2.4.4 was used that I started using too and b) the comments stated **" Although I learned a lot about Grails by reading this book .."**  and **"I still refer to the book for this info. And I like the coverage of Gorm.."**  , the topic being central to my line of work, I would like to hear your recommendations on  this book for a beginner like me.

Comment: Yes, that is my review. I don't mind discussing it, but not here on StackOverflow.

Comment: totally agree!  respect your professionalism! s/g, on your google chats, would my participation as a mere spectator hinder others progress? considering the fact that I d/l the s/w last month and wrote one simple domain class that has to be resolved yet,not sure I would be adding value. I read your ~/grails on the h/outs and gather that it is a forum where there is app build hack, of sorts, as a central theme.

Comment: Correct, the idea is to simulate a work environment where there are a handful of developers, each with different levels of Grails experience, and "management" has handed them the task of building a web app. So that's the theme. Yes, you are free to be a spectator. Since SO is not a chat-room, here's what you can do. Go to my Google+ page and follow me: https://plus.google.com/109886199751744223967 Then, go to https://hangouts.google.com/ and click on the icon that looks like a couple of people. Search for "Emmanuel Rosa", you should see my mugshot. Then click on "me" to send a message.